# What is a flexible database?

Tags: database, flexibility

I've seen many articles about database being flexible and that makes it advantageous. But what makes it like that? What does database flexibility really give, couldn't find any particular info that would explain exactly that. Could you please explain that to me?
Let say what does flexibility mean amongst NoSQL, SQL and NewSQL?

Comment: Can you link to one or three of these articles?

Comment: http://dataconomy.com/sql-vs-nosql-vs-newsql-finding-the-right-solution/

Comment: its kinda messy how they talk about it and I can't get the whole picture of it. Need someone to chew this up for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article in your comment equates flexibility with lack of schema. Absence of schema gives more flexibility when writing - you're not constrained to a predefined structure and can store complex data without decomposing it into ground facts. However, it means less flexibility when reading. Regular and consistent data supports more operations without conditional logic, and simple facts can be more easily combined into any required structure.